# Interactive HTML webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, interactive

***EDIT:*** Thanks for a lot of great examples on how to solve these. I cant decide between who to accept yet, but I will go though all examples and see which I like the most. Great feedback guys! =D

---

I normally do these kind of things in flash, but this time it has to be compatible with mac, iPads and all those units too.

So, what do I need help with?

I've got a picture, with some "hotspots" on. I want to be able to click any of those hotspots to show some information.

This should be fairly basic and easy to achieve, but since I've never done this in html before I have to ask you guys =)

So, what would be the best way to do this? It have to be compatible with any browser and device, and it doesnt need to be very advanced. If it's possible to add effects to the box (sliding out, fading in, or anything like that) then thats a nice bonus, but not something I need.

Any help would be great!

**BREAKDOWN:**

I have a background image with some "hotspots" (numbers 1 and 2 in my example). The users should be able to either hover the mouse over any of these or click it to get more information, as seen in picture #2

[image: http://i50.tinypic.com/so5nw1.jpg]

---

This is that happens when you hover/click any of these hotspots.
Text and image is displayed inside a nice little info box.

[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/1449o28.jpg]

---

If the user clicks "more information" it will open up even further to display more information if available. Like in this img:

[image: http://i50.tinypic.com/2502fzq.jpg]

Comment: html map will be your friend :)

Comment: How would I go about to make the "hotspots" from the HTML Map trigger a popup instead of redirecting to another image?

Comment: It could possibly be overkill, but using the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) could help you

Comment: Add target="_new" to your image map link, as in `<area shape=rect coords="11,22,33,44" href="http://www.website.com/"target="_blank">`

Comment: Bootstrap might work. =) Either way, it looks sweet! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the Javascript approach is really necessary here. I created a little CSS-only mock-up for you on [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/ahatir/1).

Basically the point is that you enclose the image in a *relatively positioned `div`*, then absolute position the hotspots inside the same `div`. Inside the hotspots `div`s you will have the more info elements, showing only on `:hover` of their parents.

This makes it simple, and far more accessible.

### Update: cropping the image equally from both sides

If you want to keep the image centered and still not use any javascript, you could set the required image as a `background-image` of the container, and setting its `background-position` parameters to `center center`.

You would have to make sure that the `width` of this `div` is set to the width of your image, and the `max-width` to 100%, so that when the window gets resized below the image width it stays at the center.

Now, a problem that I encountered here is how to make the hotspots stay center relatively to the image. I solved it this way:

I created a wrapper `div` for the hotspots with these characteristics:

```
margin:   0 auto;
position: relative;
width:    0px;
```

This basically makes sure that the wrapper `div` finds the center of our image. Then, you would position the hotspots **relatively to the top-center position** of the image, instead of the **top-left** as a starting point.

Then you have what you are looking for.

[**Working demo**](http://jsbin.com/ahatir/5)

Comment: How to I make my main wrapper div stay centered vertically on screen? If the screen is smaller than the image width I want it centered with no scrollbars. So it's cutting off the right and left side equally.

Comment: I think this is a fairly different question from the original one, perhaps you should open a new question. By centered you mean [**this**](http://jsbin.com/ahatir/4)? Can you be more specific as what do you mean with the second statement?

Comment: Yes, almost like that. Except when you make the width of the browser smaller than the image, I want it to still stay centered. Which means it will be cropped equally on both left and right side.

Comment: Ok, you gave me an interesting problem to solve there. But here you go, I updated my answer to meet your requirements.

Comment: Hey mate. Got another wuick question for you. I need my divs to span upwards when more information is entered, because the arrow is now on the bottom. How would I do that?

Comment: Uhm, wait, I didn't get what's your goal. Can you elaborate a bit more? If it's too complicated of an edit consider opening another question.

Comment: I've got a div with all the content for my hotspot information. I need to use the same css for different hotspots (different heights, depending on how much text is inside). So what I need, is to have the inner div (containing my text) scale to fit the content. If I have little text, this div is not very high. If i have more text, the div gets higher. But because I have this information on top (over, in pixels, not Z) of the button, I need it to "grow" upwards, instead of downwards (which is how it normally works.)

Comment: Could you make a [**fiddle**](http://jsbin.com)? It would be so much easier to understand for me.

Comment: jsbin.com/omuwap/1  Images are not uploaded. If you add more text to the div, then the text flows over the bottom of the div, instead of stretching upwards to allow the added content. It's a bit messy. Sorry.

Comment: I am sorry, but I really cannot grasp what you mean. If you add text to which div? Do a few fiddles, perhaps screenshots so I could understand better (as you did in your question). When you add content to some element, the element stretches downwards as it is expected to be in the **scroll-like** prototype which is a web page. Is it this your problem? You would like that when you add content the div would move all the content upwards? Perhaps in the way this very comment text-box works?

Comment: Sorry. Check now: www.jsbin.com/omuwap/2   You can see that the text is too long for the containing box. I need this box to be dynamic. It should scale to fit the content (the text). Also, clicking the "close" icon does not work. And the "More InformatioN" tab should display a youtube video to the right, not below the content.

Comment: Doh, sorry mate. I think I figured it out. Bottom:0; and height:auto;     I feel really ashamed.... -.-

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach, and in my opinion far superior to using a map or excessive JS. Place `<div>` elements on top of the element with the background-image and have HTML and CSS do the heavy lifting for you.

[image: Image of my example]

[See it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycSLQ/)

**HTML**

The HTML should seem pretty each enough to understand, we create `<div>`s with the class `hotspot` and rely on certain things being present. Namely `.text` (to show digit), `.hover-popup` (to show on hover) and `.click-popup` (which is inside `.hover-popup` and is shown when clicked).

```
<div id="hotspot1" class="hotspot">
    <div class="text">1</div>
    <div class="hover-popup">
        I was hovered!
        <div class="click-popup">
            I was clicked on!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="hotspot2" class="hotspot">
    <div class="text">2</div>
    <div class="hover-popup">
        I was hovered!
        <div class="click-popup">
            I was clicked on!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

This is where most of the magic happens, see the comments for further explanation.

```
/* These two position each hotspot */
#hotspot1 {
    left:15%; /* we could use px or position right or bottom also */
    top:20%;
}

#hotspot2 {
    left:35%;
    top:25%;
}

/* General styles on the hotspot */
.hotspot {
    border-radius:50%;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#CCC;
    position:absolute;
}

.hotspot .text {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}

/* Show the pointer on hover to signify a click event */
.hotspot .text:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* hide them by default and bring them to the front */
.hover-popup,
.click-popup {
    display:none;
    z-index:1;
}

/* show when clicked */
.hotspot.clicked .click-popup {
    display:block;
}

/* show and position when clicked */
.hotspot:hover .hover-popup {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#BBB;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

**JavaScript (with jQuery)**

Unfortunately you're going to have to use some JavaScript for the clicking part as CSS doesn't have a 'clicked' state (outside of hacks with checkboxes). I'm using jQuery because it's dead easy to do what I want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hotspot').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

**Creating the arrow**

Over at [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/speech-bubble-arrows-that-inherit-parent-color/) you can find a tutorial for attaching an arrow to a element using the `:before` and/or `:after` pseudo-elements. You can even 'simulate' a border around them by placing the `:after` element on top of the `:before`. But yea, lots of resources on how to do this.

Comment: I have a doubt. When I am using the above code inside another div container. In this container, I have set the background image. When I insert these hotspots, only the upper part of the background image is visible. I want my background image to be visible completely just like <img> tag would have shown. So that over that I can insert hotspots anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the onclick or OnMouseOver event in the map area (define the href as "").

An example using OnMouseOver is here: http://www.omegagrafix.com/mouseover/mousimap.html

Answer (score 0):

Give a class for that image in html (Ex: imgclass). And in javascript(using jquery), build that hover box in html format and bind it to 'mouseover' event of that image.

For example:

```
 function bindhtmltoimage() {
    myimg = $('body').find('.imgclass');
    divSlot.each(function (index) {
        $(this).bind('mouseover', function () {
            try {
                //position the hover box on image. you can customize the y and x axis to place it left or right.
                var x = $(this).offset().left;
                var y = $(this).offset().top;
                var position = $(window).height() - ($("#divHover").height() + y);
                var widthposition = $(window).width() - ($("#divHover").width() + x);
                if (position < 0 || widthposition < 0) {
                    if (position < 0) {
                        $("#divHover").css({
                            position: 'absolute',
                            left: x + 20,
                            top: y - $("#divHover").height() - 20
                        });
                    }
                    if (widthposition < 0) {
                        $("#divHover").css({
                            position: 'absolute',
                            left: x - $("#divHover").width(),
                            top: y + 20
                        });
                    }
                }

                //build your html string for that hover box and apply to it.
                $('#divHover').html("your Html content for that box goes here");
                $('#divHover').show();

                //if you want the box dynamically generated. create the html content and append to the dom.
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

it will work fine in desktop and mobile. if you face any problem in touch devices, bind the function to click event instead of 'mouseover'.

Also, for map approach, i strongly recommend SVG instead of images.